# Is the space of periodic real sequences a closed subspace of the bounded real sequences?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $E$ be the set of bounded real sequences equipped with the following norm:

$$||(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}||_{\infty}=\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|a_n|$$

Let $P$ be the set of real periodic sequences, which is a subspace of $E$.

**Is $P$ is closed in $E$?**

---

I suspect the answer is yes. I tried of a good while to construct a counterexample but failed.

Edit: what I tried...

Suppose $(s_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of elements of $P$ with limit $a$ in $E$, and let $p_n$ denotes the period of $s_n$. If $(p_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded then there is some number $p$ and a subsequence of $(s_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in which each term is a sequence of period $p$, which implies $s$ has period $p$.

To find a counterexample we would thus need $(p_n)$ unbounded and, assuming without loss of generality that $(p_n)$ is increasing, we would even need $p_{n+1}-p_n$ to be unbounded. Finally the limit sequence $a$ would need to satisfy for all $k$ and $m$: $a_{k+mp_n} \to a_{k}$  as $n$ tends to infinity. Already constructing such a limit sequence $a$ is far from obvious!

Comment: How about considering a sequence of periodic sequences of different periods?

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to prove a more abstract result. Try to prove the following generalization: A subspace of Banach space of countable dimension is not closed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a prime $p$, consider the sequence $x^{(p)}$ with

$$x^{(p)}_n = \begin{cases} 1 &, p \mid n \\ 0 &, p \nmid n\end{cases}$$

and then

$$x = \sum_p 2^{-p}\cdot x^{(p)}.$$

Show that $x$ is not periodic.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are you claiming that  $x^(p)$ (which is indeed a sequence of elements of $P$) tends towards $x$ (which is indeed not in $P$)? That is not true.

Comment: No, I claim that the sequence of partial sums of the series, which is a sequence in $P$, converges to $x$.

Comment: Ah I see. Well that's amazing, how did you construct this counterexample?

Comment: Once one has noticed that a construction by a series is probably easier than directly describing a Cauchy sequence, it is not hard to construct examples. Almost everything with increasing periods is going to work. (Though it's not always as easy to prove that it works. Having a sum with $x_1 = 0$ and $x_n > 0$ for all $n\neq 1$ makes the proof easy.)

Comment: i think looking for a Cauchy sequence not be sufficient anyways, right? $E$ is not complete as far as i can see, so not every Cauchy sequence converges...

Comment: $E$ is complete, it's also known under the name $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$ [or $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R})$ to distinguish it from the space of bounded complex sequences]. It's also $L^{\infty}(\zeta)$ where $\zeta$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$.